# Рассчитать необходимое время в до заданного времени на неделе.

Tags: jquery, время, дата, javascript

Добрый день, интересует меня следующий вопрос.
У меня имеется список из повторяющихся событий, состоящий из дней недели и времени.

Пример: пн, вт, сб - 13:00, 18:35;

Т.е событие происходит каждый пн, вт, сб в 13:00 и 18:35

Необходимо посчитать сколько времени в миллисекундах осталось до ближайшего события.

Для расчета времени по дате есть пример

```
var today = new Date().getTime();
var end = new Date(2014,0,1).getTime();
var dateX = new Date(end-today);
var perDays = 60*60*1000*24;
date_to_write = '' + (Math.round(dateX/perDays)) + ' дней, ' + dateX.getUTCHours().toString() + 'ч. ' + dateX.getMinutes().toString() + 'м. ' + dateX.getSeconds().toString() + 'c.';
$('.event-block .event-timer').text(date_to_write);
```

Но как быть с моей задачей?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Находим ближайший день, который удовлетворяет условию: Если это пн||вт||сб && время больше либо равно 13:00 и меньше либо равно 18 35. Считаем разность.

```
/**
 * дни недели, которые нам нужны
 */
var days = [1, 2];
/**
 * время с и до
 */
var times = [
    [13,00],
    [18,35]
];

var dateObj = new Date();
var start = dateObj.getDay(), out_days = 1;

if(days.indexOf(start) != -1 
    && dateObj.getHours() >= times[0][0]
    && dateObj.getMinutes() >= times[0][1] 
    && dateObj.getHours() <= times[1][0]
    && dateObj.getMinutes() <= times[1][1]
) {
    var toEvent = dateObj;
}
else {
    var toEvent = new Date();

    for(;; start++, out_days++) {
        if(days.indexOf(start) != -1) {
            toEvent = new Date(toEvent.setDate(toEvent.getDate() + out_days));
            toEvent.setHours(times[0][0]);
            toEvent.setMinutes(times[0][1]);
            toEvent.setSeconds(0);
            break;
        }
        start>=6?start=0:null;
    }
}

console.log(toEvent.getTime() - dateObj.getTime()); //ms
```